# Chrome extensions support copy image to clipboard?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I search in goggle and didn't find any answer.
The new clipboard API support copy image to clipboard by using `document.exec command`.
If yes, How can I copy image `data url` to clipboard as image?

I am the developer of Webpage Screenshot extension and I search for a way to copy the image to clipboard.
I also search for a way to open the image with specific software.

Answer (score 1):

I am developing a ScreenShotShare chrome extension, I have the need to copy clipped image to clipboard as well. And I found the solution works for me.
1. Add "clipboardWrite","clipboardRead" to the permissions in manifest.json file
2. do copy work in the background.html with background.js
3. add  to background.html 
4. I implement the "copyImageToClipboard" to function in background.js

```
copyImageToClipboard: function () {
    var img = $('clipboard-img');
    img.src = localStorage[this.screenshotURIName]; // I store the image URI in localStorage
    var div = $('clipboard-div');
    div.contentEditable = true;
    var range;
    if (document.createRange) {
      range = document.createRange();
      range.selectNodeContents(div);
      window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
      window.getSelection().addRange(range);
      div.focus();
      document.execCommand('copy');
    }
    div.contentEditable = false;
  }
```

Comment: It is not working for me. Nothing copies (only image title if I specify). Do you have any working example?

Comment: I found that this way only work for text editor such as Evernote, and not work for word and ipages. A friend told me : focus the img and trigger cmd+c or ctrl+c, I have tried, but not success. Some guy said in webkit, there is a bug for overwrite keyCode of KeyboardEvent, I tried http://jsbin.com/EruQEFoH/2/edit, but not successful yet

Answer (score 1):

clipboardData API is almost implemented in all the browser, so instead docuemnt.exec command, you can try below also refer the below link which has similar use case as yours.

https://www.lucidchart.com/techblog/2014/12/02/definitive-guide-copying-pasting-javascript/

```js
clipboardData.setData('text/plain', selection.getText());
clipboardData.setData('application/officeObj', selection.serialize());
clipboardData.setData('image/bmp', draw(selection));
clipboardData.setData('text/html', ...);
```

Comment: you can install lucidchart chrome extension and play aruond with it, you will know you can copy paste their custom drawing.

Answer (score -1):

Today 7 years later, it's the most starred issue in Google Chrome. To copy images using JavaScript. And now it's possible!

Chrome 76 Beta supports it: https://blog.chromium.org/2019/06/chrome-76-beta-dark-mode-payments-new.html

You can read the full draft here:
https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5074658793619456

and here: https://w3c.github.io/clipboard-apis/#async-clipboard-api

Example:

```
var data = new Blob(["iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mNk+P+/HgAFhAJ/wlseKgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="], {type : "image/png"});

  const clipboardItemInput = new ClipboardItem({'image/png' : blobInput});
  await navigator.clipboard.write([clipboardItemInput]);
```

You can test it here: http://w3c-test.org/clipboard-apis/async-write-image-read-image-manual.https.html

(Now it support only Chrome 76 beta)